# How to show newly inserted records from database in main window?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm making a wpf application for an auction. Main window looks like: http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/91622733/file.html

[image: main window]

Main window code:

```
  namespace WpfApplication25
{
    /// <summary> <br>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml <br>
    /// </summary> <br> 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window <br>
    {

        int count = 120;
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmr = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);

            DataTable aukcijeTable = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;");
            SqlDataAdapter aukcDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from auctions", conn);

            aukcDa.Fill(aukcijeTable);
            aukcija_bazeDataGrid.DataContext = aukcijeTable;


        }



        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = count -= 1;
            if (count == 0 )
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Auction completed");
                tmr.Stop();
                count = 120;
            }
            else
            {


            }

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 popup = new Form1();
            popup.ShowDialog();
            popup.Dispose();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 popup = new Form2();
            popup.ShowDialog();

            popup.Dispose();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tmr.Start();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;")) 

            {
                DataTable cena1 = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(" UPDATE auctions SET current_price = current_price + 1", conn);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("UPDATE auctions SET current_price = current_price + 1", conn);
                DA.Fill(cena1);
                //DA.Update(cena1);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(DA); //novo
                DA.Update(cena1); //novo
                conn.Close(); 

            }

        }


        private void aukcija_bazeDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            tmr.Start();

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Auction completed!");
            count = 120;
        }


    }
}
```

Also, I've made a new form for adding new auctions, it looks like this:
http://www8.zippyshare.com/v/35519167/file.html.

[image: new auction]

Code for that new form:

```
namespace WpfApplication25    {
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                     @"data source=(local);
                     database=Aukcija;
                     integrated security=true;"))
        {
            DataTable aukcijeTable = new DataTable(); //novo

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Auctions (item_name, start_price, current_price ) VALUES (@item_name, @start_price, @current_price)");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_price", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@current_price", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
            connection.Close();



        }
    }
}}
```

When I click on `button1_Click` it opens me a new form and I fill it with new auction information, and when I click OK nothing happens. I have to close my application and open it again to show me newly inserted records from the DataBase.

What am I missing in the code? **I need something to refresh(update) main window automatically when I press OK...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MainForm`(where you open the update-form) replace the part where you're currently opening the update-form with the following code:

```
if (popup.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    //to update your DataGrid, try the following:            
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;");
    SqlDataAdapter aukcDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from auctions", conn);
    aukcDa.Update(aukcija_bazeDataGrid.DataContext as System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid);
}
```

EDIT: Add the following to your `button1_click`-method of your Form2-class:

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

Comment: A part of code: if (updateForm.ShowDialog....
what do you mean with "updateForm" ? is that my Form2 ?

Comment: Yes, thats your Form2.

Comment: Here`s a picture of errors I get when I copy your code:
[link](http://www39.zippyshare.com/v/18763104/file.html)

Comment: @МаркоЛучић Updated my answer, but you could have figured out those mistakes by yourself, you won't learn anything if you ask because of every little error...

Comment: upvote for your effort bro :) that is a nice and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

sorry i can't access links that you provided.
You have to return the newly added object in a way to display in mainwindow, I don't know in which way you display objects, it must be datagrid I think, so after inserting newly created object into database, you have to add that object manually into datagrid. because datagrid is not aware of newly inserted object.

You can try public properties like ItemName, StartPrice, CurrentPrice, on insertingForm, filling them with inserting values, and in mainwindow, get them and add into datagrid

like this

```
namespace WpfApplication25    {
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

public string ItemName{get;set;}
public string CurrentPrice{get;set;}
public string StartPrice{get;set;}

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                     @"data source=(local);
                     database=Aukcija;
                     integrated security=true;"))
        {
            DataTable aukcijeTable = new DataTable(); //novo
            ItemName = textBox1.Text;
            CurrentPrice = textBox3.Text;
            StartPrice = textBox2.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Auctions (item_name, start_price, current_price ) VALUES (@item_name, @start_price, @current_price)");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_price", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@current_price", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
            connection.Close();



        }
    }
}}
```

and in mainwindow after showing insertng form get the properties values

```
namespace WpfApplication25
{
    /// <summary> <br>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml <br>
    /// </summary> <br> 
    public partial class MainWindow : Window <br>
    {

        int count = 120;
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer tmr = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

private DataTable aukcijeTable;        
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);

            aukcijeTable = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;");
            SqlDataAdapter aukcDa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from auctions", conn);

            aukcDa.Fill(aukcijeTable);
            aukcija_bazeDataGrid.DataContext = aukcijeTable;


        }



        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = count -= 1;
            if (count == 0 )
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Auction completed");
                tmr.Stop();
                count = 120;
            }
            else
            {


            }

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 popup = new Form1();
            popup.ShowDialog();
            popup.Dispose();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 popup = new Form2();
            if(popup.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK){

                var newRow = aukcijeTable.NewRow();
                newRpw[0] = popup.ItemName;
                newRow[1] = popup.StartPrice;
                newRow[2] = popup.CurrentPrice;
                aukcijeTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
                aukcija_bazeDataGrid.Refresh();

            }

            popup.Dispose();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tmr.Start();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=(local);database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;")) 

            {
                DataTable cena1 = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(" UPDATE auctions SET current_price = current_price + 1", conn);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("UPDATE auctions SET current_price = current_price + 1", conn);
                DA.Fill(cena1);
                //DA.Update(cena1);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(DA); //novo
                DA.Update(cena1); //novo
                conn.Close(); 

            }

        }


        private void aukcija_bazeDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            tmr.Start();

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tmr.Stop();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Auction completed!");
            count = 120;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post, take a look on pictures... I have tried your code but still the same... If you want, I will send you my project. Thanks

Comment: What should I write...?

Comment: i will edit my answer one more time, first you have to make datatbale that using as datasource of grid, global

Comment: edited, make datatable global, and add new row to it, then refresh datagrid

Comment: Sorry, but one more thing...im getting this error: [link](http://www75.zippyshare.com/v/52536974/file.html)

Comment: I can not open zippyshare links, and you have to select one answer or at least upvote them if they help.